# raw attribute in Message Resource in Ballerina/gmail package

Tags: ballerina

```
var response = gmailClient->readMessage(userId,msg_id);
gmail:Message msg;
match response {
    gmail:Message m => msg = m;
    gmail:GmailError err=> io:println(err);
}
gmail:MessageBodyPart msg_body = msg["plainTextBodyPart"];
string msg_content = msg["raw"];
```

When I use 'plainTextBodyPart' attribute in Message resource in ballerina/Gmail package,it returns the message body correctly .But if I use the 'raw' attribute of the same resource as above, it returns a null value.What is the error in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The readMessage() function of Ballerina GmailConnector[1] accepts 4 parameters with 2 of them being optional. The **format** and **metadataHeaders** parameters are optional. You can refer the Gmail API documentation as well [2].

In your case, since you are not passing any value for **format**, your readMessage request will have the default format which is **"FORMAT_FULL"** [3]. It is stated in the API documentation[1] as well. So the response you get for that from Gmail API will not have the field **"raw"** and the **"raw"** string field of **Message** resource of the connector will be empty [4]. So you would get an empty string when you try access it as **msg["raw"]**.

Is it an empty string or a null value you are getting? Because ideally it should return an empty string for your code, and when I tried the same code I got an empty string for the **"raw"** field as expected.

If you want to get the entire email message in an RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string using **"raw"** field, invoke the readMessage function as below by providing the format as **FORMAT_RAW**,

```
var response = gmailEP->readMessage(userId, messageId, format = gmail:FORMAT_RAW);
```

Let me know if this helps you.

[1] https://central.ballerina.io/wso2/gmail

[2] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

[3] https://github.com/wso2-ballerina/package-gmail/blob/master/gmail/gmail_connector.bal#L75

[4] https://github.com/wso2-ballerina/package-gmail/blob/master/gmail/gmail_data_mappings.bal#L40